# URL unescape in Netty for percent-encoding

Tags: java, http, netty

I am developing a public REST API service using Netty. I am expecting some users will submit percent-encoded URL, for example with %20 for space.I need to unescape the percent-ecoded URL.

Is there a built in Netty API for this? Or is there any third party Java API for it?

I did search for a solution but could not find one.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you considered the `java.net.URLDecoder` class from the JRE itself ?

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works. I din't know this class.

Answer (score 0):

Netty has own class for that - `io.netty.handler.codec.http.QueryStringDecoder`. It is also preferred against `java.net.URLDecoder` as it is much faster.

Usage example:

```
    //netty http request object
    HttpRequest httpRequest = ...;
    QueryStringDecoder decoder = new QueryStringDecoder(httpRequest.uri());
    decoder.parameters().get("value");
```